# Collection of user input into a variable to be appended to a file

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a shell script to collect user input to later be appended into a text file.
Here's what I am working with:

```
 note_file=~/project_2/file
 loop_test=y
 while test "$loop_test" = "y"
 do
  clear
  tput cup 1 4; echo "     Note Sheet Addition     "
  tput cup 2 4; echo "============================="
  tput cup 4 4; echo "Note: "
  tput cup 5 4; echo "Add Another? (Y)es or (Q)uit: "
  tput cup 4 10; read note
if test $note = "q"
then
 clear; exit
fi
 if test "$note" != ""
 then
  echo "$note:" >> $note_file
 fi
  tput cup 5 33; read hoop_test
 if [ "$hoop_test" = "q" ]
 then
  clear; exit
 fi
done
```

now my problem is that I want to store an entire sentence in the note variable and not just a single arguement.
i.e. note="this is a note or some other general text stuff"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: doesn't `read note` keep the full line entered as a single string, i.e., including the spaces?

Comment: Other than the obvious `read hoop_test` instead of `read loop_test`

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious `hoop` `loop` spelling issue, and the `:` you append to each `note` (that may be intentional, dunno), your entire issue causing the error when you enter more than a single word is your failure to ***quote*** your variable when using `test`, e.g.

```
    if test "${note,,}" = "q"   ## always quote variables in test
```

Notice the `"..."` (without the quotes, it's `test some words = "q"` which prompts the error: `test: too many arguments` -- sound familiar?) Properly quoted it is `test "some words" = "q"` which is fine.

(the parameter expansion with `,,` just converts the contents of `note` to *lower-case* to handle `Q` or `q` for quit)

Other than those issues (and needing to reset `loop_test` to `y` explicitly at the end), your script works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

note_file=~/project_2/file
note=""
loop_test=y

while test "$loop_test" = "y"
do
    clear
    tput cup 1 4; echo "     Note Sheet Addition     "
    tput cup 2 4; echo "============================="
    tput cup 4 4; echo "Note: "
    tput cup 5 4; echo "Add Another? (Y)es or (Q)uit: "
    tput cup 4 10; read note

    if test "${note,,}" = "q"   ## always quote variables in test
    then
        clear; exit
    fi

    if test "$note" != ""
    then
        echo "$note" >> "$note_file"
    fi

    tput cup 5 34; read loop_test

    if [ "${loop_test,,}" = "q" ]
    then
        clear; exit
    else
        loop_test=y
    fi
done
```